# Monkeylearn responds with status code 423 using Java

Tags: java, monkeylearn

I am trying to connect to Monkey Learn URL but the error that I get is as follows:

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 423 for URL: https://api.monkeylearn.com/v2/classifiers/cl_rFrQ66gZ/classify/
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1245)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:234)
        at app.Main.main(Main.java:51)
```

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)

What is the problem?

Here is my sample code:

```
//Create connection
            url = new URL ("https://api.monkeylearn.com/v2/classifiers/cl_rFrQ66gZ/classify/");
            connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization",
                "d6589857b53d9b732591b84c16016ac8dd1a4c43");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "application/json");

            connection.setUseCaches (false);
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);

            //Send request
            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());

            wr.write ("{\"text_list\": [\"some text to test\", \"some more text\"]}");
            wr.flush ();
            wr.close ();
```

Comment: From wikipedia "423 Locked (WebDAV; RFC 4918) The resource that is being accessed is locked."

Answer (score 1):

You can get a detailed error message by printing the response body.

You're missing something in the Authorization request header the value should start with "Token ", change it for something like this:

```
connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization",
                              "Token d6589857b53d9b732591b84c16016ac8dd1a4c43");
```

Finally, note that you posted your API key, please revoke it as soon as posible using monkeylearn web UI.